# Trying to get an "adjusted" ratio of two numbers

Tags: c++

I would like to do this

I have two numbers, A and B, where it can be A greater or smaller than B. What I want to do:

1. Compare B with A
2. If their ratio is "ouside" of a range, then take a random number and add it to "A" - Now check if their new ratio meets the condition

   ```
   0.95 < ratio < 1.05
   ```
3. if not, try with another random.

My problem is that I ran into infinite loops... this is what I do:

```
float ratio = A/B;

if (ratio < 0.95  || ratio > 1.05) {
    do {
        // randomly take a negative or positive number
        float random_n = ((float)rand())/RAND_MAX - 0.50; 
        // get an even smaller step
        random_n *= 0.1;
        // add or subtract the random number (depending on its sign)
        A += random_n;
        // form the ratio again 
        ratio = A / B;
        cout << "lets see " << A  << "  " << B << "  " << ratio << endl;        
    }
    while (ratio > 0.95 || ratio < 1.05);
}
```

Comment: `while(ratio >0.95 || ratio<1.05);`
Look carefully at this line and what it's doing.

Comment: `((float)rand())/RAND_MAX * - 0.50` I don't think you meant to multiply by a negative one-half, but rather to subtract one half. Drop the star.

Comment: Actually, I ve tried to "split" to two different snippets ie a case when ratio>0.5 and another where ratio<1.05 - but still infinite loops

Comment: @IgorTandetnik - yes, just a typo ;-) thanks

Comment: Even with the loop condition corrected, waiting for a random walk to bring the ratio into range could take rather long. What's the point of the exercise, if you don't mind me asking? What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: An `if` containing `do ... while` (with the same condition) is exactly the same than `while ...` -- The difference between a `do .. while` loop and a `while` loop is that the former does not check the condition in the first iteration (it will iterate at least once), while the latter also checks before iterating for the very first time.

Comment: There's no reason to have if...do...while, just a while would be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition should be:

```
while (ratio <= 0.95 || ratio >= 1.05);
```

You got the "<" and ">" mixed up. *ratio* is **not** between 0.95 and 1.05 if it's less or equal than 0.95 or greater or equal than 1.05.

It's easy to avoid such mistakes if you remember how you negate a conjunction:

> **NOT** (0.95 < ratio < 1.05) === **NOT** (0.95 < ratio **AND** ratio < 1.05) ====
>   [...]

The rule is: change every **AND** to **OR** and negate all sub-expressions:

> [...] === (**NOT** (0.95 < ratio) **OR NOT** (ratio < 1.05)) ====
>   (0.95 >= ratio **OR** ratio >= 1.05) === (ratio <= 0.95 **OR** ratio >= 1.05)

Answer (score 1):

Your do..while loop condition should be

`while(ratio <= 0.95 || ratio =>1.05)`

Comment: No, it should be `while(ratio < 0.95 || ratio > 1.05);` and then `if/do/while` should be replaced by a simple `while`.

Comment: @Henrik while you're correct in that the OP can shorten his code by just using a standard while loop, rather then the if-do-while setup he has at the moment, Zahirdhaha is correct that the while condition should be `&&`, otherwise it is always true

Comment: @Daboyzuk -  Ok - but changing the " || " to " && " simply breaks the loop while the ratio is NOT within the specified range...

Comment: @Henrik, zahirdhada Actually two three problems in this code both answers are incomplete. one should post and cover all correction.

Comment: @Daboyzuk OP wants to loop while the ratio is *outside* the range.

Comment: @Henrik You're correct, I didn't read the question properly, my mistake.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't read the question properly. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is you're increasing A and never changing B

and still expect ratio to be in (0.95,1.05) . This depends on initial value of A and B to break the loop.

Try:

```
    B=rand()%RAND_MAX;

    do {
    A=rand()%RAND_MAX;
    ratio = A/B;
    cout<<"lets see "<< A  <<"  "<< B <<"  "<<ratio<<endl;        

   }while(ratio <0.95 || ratio>1.05);
```

Then can divide A and B by power of ten as per your needs.

Also use `srand(time(0))` for different random values on successive runs

Comment: Well, this is not the case - I am not allowed the change both numbers "randomly". Practically, I am allowed to change one following a gaussian distribution with mean = A and sigma=sqrt(A), but for the shake of easiness, I changed the example to change the A with a random number- Furthermore, in your example one would get any kind of "random" pair that satisfies the condition, and this is not the purpose. Thanks for the try though

Comment: @Alex check now, take any B. Also, can use 100 or any value instead of RANDMAX. Also it does stop!